# Pop & push automatic configurations as a reaction on priority release builds

Tags: build, configuration, teamcity, release

Within our company we use TeamCity for both automatically triggered build configurations, that are triggered quite regularly, and also manual not-as-often build configurations.

Examples of automatic builds are: up-to-date light builds, tests, etc. These are usually triggered because new code/data is available.

Currently, there is big chained process for a release of our product on all platforms. This is done manually by running the last composing build config, and it will do all the build configurations it needs to. None of them are ever automatically triggered, and all are unique to the release build chain.

My questions are, as the amount of agents we have available is quite limited, is it possible that the release process has priority in a way that it would:

- Pop any automatic builds and add them again to the queue (just cancelling would be fine, but less desirable) as long as the release chain is ongoing?
- Delay any automatic trigger build until the release build chain is finished?

I would understand that there is no existing solution for this, as the only thing I'm using for now is the priority classes. And even though it does work nicely for deciding what stuff on the queue to execute first, it doesn't affect any ongoing build process.

Do you know a great solution for that, or have an idea on how I could tackle this myself by implementing something using, for example, the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity have [custom build queue priorities feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Ordering+Build+Queue#OrderingBuildQueue-ManagingBuildPriorities). You can configure your release process build configurations to have higher priority, so they will run before any non-prioritized build, and there no need to remove/readd builds from/into queue.

Comment: As in my description, I already use these priority classes. And while they work nicely for starting builds based on priority from the queue. It doesn't solve the "problems" I'm trying to solve here:

The goal is more that ongoing builds would cancel based on the manual start of an important build chain. So that we don't have to kill ourselves manually to free up agents when these builds need to happen.